# Cocoa Pod setup - Not installing after 72%

Tags: git, cocoapods

I am not able to understand why pod setup is taking long time and finally gives this error

[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress

> Cloning into 'master'... remote: Counting objects: 1409076, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1810/1810), done.         error:
>   RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806397.00 KiB/s
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF fatal:
>   index-pack failed

I tried many answers from Stack Overflow, but could not make it fix.

I tried pod setup --verbose, but not able to figure out the right error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi After an Hour of struggle. I tried these steps and make it fix-

> - sudo gem uninstall --all
> - sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
> - pod setup

Note - Please wait till you get success message or failure message. it took bit a time (usually 10 to 5 minutes) for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

~/.cocoapods is not supposed to be a git repository, ~/.cocoapods/repos is a directory which contains Sources which may be git repositories.

It looks like your issue is that ~/.cocoapods/repos/master is not a git repository, and you should probably run rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master && pod setup

[6302](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6302)